# new mailing send test no work

Tags: civimail

i already set send email config on (civicrm/admin/setting/smtp?reset=1), i can send email to contact list peoples, but i can not send mailing on new mailing page, i try to click "send test" , have error
"could not identify any recipients. perhaps your test group is empty, or you tried sending to contacts that do not exist and you have no permission to add contacts.",
my email to and from is white list,so i dont know why not working,i need extra setting on civicrm??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to include a group in the Recipients field with at least one contact in it.

Comment: i try again, but also have error message

Comment: what is the new error msg?